# Do I need a transit visa for London, UK?

Tags: transit, uk, london

I'm Chinese citizen, leaving in Italy and in possession of an unlimited permission of stay in Italy, I flow from MILAN to BEIJING via LONDON with return ticket, everything = OK,

by getting to the BEIJING airport for the return flight via LONDON to MILAN I have got the check-in refused becouse of laps of TRANSIT VISA for LONDON

Can you pls. confirm that I'm exempted from transit visa,

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Please do not write your title in all caps.

Comment: EU permanent residents don't need a transit visa to transit the UK airside. But you must have your residence permit with you, and you will have to show it to the airline.